# Test for value in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

In SQL Server, I could say:

```
WHERE X IN(1,2)
```

How would you rewrite the following in JavaScript:

```
if (X==1 || X==2) {}
```

Comment: I wonder if I could write an IN function.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You have written valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to see if `x` is in an array.

```
if([1,2].indexOf(x) !== -1)
```

Comment: Browser compatibility of Array.indexOf looks good, starts with MSIE 9 for example
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 24):

Using [Array `.includes` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
if ([1, 2].includes(x)) {
  // array has x
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer for modern browsers, but I'm afraid IE doesn't support it. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, IE won't work. Use it with polyfill or in conjunction with a transpiler (e.g. Babel / Typescript)

Comment: It makes me cooler when my answer is short.

Answer (score 9):

Try using an array, and then its `.indexOf()`.

```
 var myNumbers = [1,2];
 var foo = 4;
 var bar = 1;

 var exists = (myNumbers.indexOf(bar) > -1); //true
 var notExists = (myNumbers.indexOf(foo) > -1); //false
```

Comment: Note: Not all browsers come with `Array.indexOf`

Comment: IE7 and below don't support it apparently.. here's more info and a drop in fallback http://soledadpenades.com/2007/05/17/arrayindexof-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 7):

There's no silver bullet. There will be a few gotchas.

If you do `indexOf` as some answers suggest, you need to remember that `Array.indexOf` is not supported in all browsers, so you need to provide your own fallback. Also this will have a performance of `O(n)` since it needs to traverse the whole array, which might not be ideal if you're dealing with a huge array.

If you use the `in` operator as other answers suggest, you need to remember that in Javascript object's properties are always strings, so don't expect `===` checks to work if you're checking for numbers.

In this particular example you suggested, I would just go for the good old `if (X==1 || X==2)`.

Comment: simple and super clean answer that assure to run on all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (x in {1:true, 2:true}) { }
```

Or, if you want to abstract it you could do it like this http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/testing_for_a_v

function oc(a)
{
  var o = {};
  for(var i=0;i

Still... not the most scalable thing to be doing

Comment: This fails If `x` contains an identifier of an “inherited” property: `var x = "constructor"; x in {1:true, 2:true}` yields true.

Comment: Thats interesting, to be honest it isn't really the nicest construct anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Requires Javascript 1.6

```
if ((new Array(1, 2)).indexOf(X) != -1) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know we have in_array() function in PHP, but I never heard of a similar function in JS.
I think you gotta do it the old way:

```
function contains(a, obj) {
  var i = a.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (a[i] === obj) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Function to convert the array into an object literal

```
function oc(a)
{
 var o = {};
 for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
 {
  o[a[i]]='';
 }
  return o;
}
```

You can call the function like

```
if( name in oc(['Tom', 'Harry','Sue']) ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just fun:

```
if (X*X+1*2 == (1+2)*X) {}
```

or self-explaining:

```
if ((X-1)*(X-2) == 0) {}
```