# How to print whole list in for loop?

Tags: javascript

I just want to practice Javascript, so I try this easy code.
In my expected that the output should be whole list.

When I use this code I only can get the output is

```
[5, 9, 17, 14, 4, 19, 11, 8, 13, 10, 18, 15, 16, 20]
```

I did not know what happened on it, and where was

```
[1,0,2,3,6,7,12...]
```

```js
var li = [5,9,17,14,1,0,4,19,11,6,8,13,10,2,18,15,16,3,12,7,20]
var length = li.length;
var x = [];
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
  if(!(li[i]in x)){
    x.push(li[i]);
  };
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: [5,9,17,14,1,0,4,19,11,6,8,13,10,2,18,15,16,3,12,7,20]

Comment: all you need just simply `console.log(li)`

Comment: This is your input data.

Comment: I knew it, but I just wanted to practice it.

Comment: `x` is an array, so when you say `something in array` it treats array as an object. `1 in x` is true because `x` has *property* `1`, which is index 1, that's why 1 don't get pushed in x

Comment: Well, if you remove the `if(!(li[i]in x))` or change the `console.log(li)` then it works properly, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: When I input the list is sorted, like [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], it can output whole list, but unsorted couldn't achieve it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Javascript if in x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356122/javascript-if-in-x) I got

> JavaScript does have an in operator, but it tests for keys and not values.

So you don't get those values because you check for the key -> 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. and at the position of e.g. item 1 in your list the 1st key is already used.

In other words what the if in your specific case actually does is `if(x.length < li[i])`.

Just to clarify `if(x.length < li[i])` is not the same as `!(li[i]in x)` in every case!

To print the whole list use `includes` for your if. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: *In other words what your if actually does is if(x.length < li[i]){*. **This is not true**. `x.length < li[i]` is **not the same** as `!(li[i]in x)`

Comment: @Adelin, of course you are right the `==` is not right here! And you are also right with `x.length < li[i]` is not the same as `!(li[i]in x)`, i never said that! But in @Steve's specific case `x.length < li[i]` has the same effect as `!(li[i]in x)` so he may got a better explanation for the `in` operator

Answer (score 8):

the condition checking `if(!(li[i]in x)){` is not correct. `in` check if keys(index) exist in the array .

Change to `if(!x.includes(li[i])){`

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value) for browser support info and alternative methods

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print each one at a line use `console.log(li[I]);` insidr the for loop, or remove everything and use `console.log[li];` to print the whole array all together